# Gitlab CI and Docker throws error when migrating

Tags: laravel, docker, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run PHPUnit tests with GitLab CI and Docker. However, when it gets to the point that I am running my migrations, I get this error:

```
$ php artisan migrate



  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  




ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
# Before Script
before_script:
    - composer self-update
    - composer config -g github-oauth.github.com $GITHUB_AUTH_KEY
    - composer install --prefer-dist
    - cp .env.example .env
    - echo "DB_HOST=mysql" >> .env
    - echo "CHALLONGE_API=$CHALLONGE_API" >> .env
    - echo "CHALLONGE_SUBDOMAIN=$CHALLONGE_SUBDOMAIN" >> .env
    - echo "EBOT_DB_PASSWORD=$EBOT_DB_PASSWORD" >> .env
    - echo "SOCKET_IO_IP=$SOCKET_IO_IP" >> .env
    - echo "REDIS_HOST=$REDIS_HOST" >> .env 
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan migrate

# Services
services:
    - mysql:lastest
    - redis:latest

# Variables
variables:
    MYSQL_USER: homestead
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME

# PHP 5.6
php:5.6:
  image: bobey/docker-gitlab-ci-runner-php5.6
  script:
    - echo "Running PHPUnit Tests"
    - php vendor/bin/phpunit --colors --debug  --coverage-text
```

Any ideas why it is throwing this error?

Comment: I think you receive this error, when you are not ssh'd in your machine. You need to `vagrant ssh`, cd into directory and `php artisan migrate`

Comment: @senty I'm fairly sure the code is run in the Docker container.

Comment: Getting this too, not sure what is causing, but I think it might be that artisan cannot connect to the db, it seems to not have a valid connection.

Comment: Ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I presume DB_HOST is set to `localhost` in your .env file, which will try to connect to the MySql server through a unix socket. However, that's not supported out of the box. Try setting it to `mysql` in your test environment instead, as explained in the docs: http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html.